# Laravel Nova Metrics Value, complex calculate

Tags: laravel, metrics, laravel-nova

I have to following models.
Manager(id,name,...)
Account(id,manager_id,...)
Subscription(id,account_id,quantity,...)

I want to get all the subscriptions of all the accounts associate with the online manager.

I tried something like this.

```
$managerAccounts = Account::where('manager_id', auth()->id())->get('id');

return $this->count($request, Subscription::where('account_id', $managerAccounts), 'quantity');
```

But this is not working properly, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do is to change it to whereIn.

$managerAccounts = Account::where('manager_id', auth()->id())->get('id');

return $this->count($request, Subscription::whereIn('account_id', $managerAccounts), 'quantity');